# Django DRF - How to do CSRF validation with token authentication

Tags: python, angularjs, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am working on REST API using Django and Django Rest Framework.
In the front-end I have AngularJs app.
I have used Token authentication for APIs. This disables the CSRF checks.

I want keep CSRF validation with REST API. How to achieve this ?

How should I get CSRF Token value so that it can be set into the header of every POST request, using interceptor of my angular application.

Comment: Why do you want to use CSRF validation, what problem are you trying to solve? There's a reason CSRF validation is disabled when using token authentication...

Comment: Yes, I think we don't need it in case of REST API with Token authentication.

Comment: @knbk could you please mention few or single reason? i am really looking for it.. is it due to that we are already validating user's token which could only be send from a trusted source?

Comment: @LalZada It's because sending the token requires an explicit action from something that knows the token. A cross-site request doesn't know the token, so it can't forge a malicious request. In the case of sessions, the session id is _always_ sent with the request, even on a cross-site request from a malicious source, so then it _is_ possible to forge a malicious request if there's not CSRF protection.

Answer (score 0):

I have this configuration in my **app.js**. Should do the trick!

```
app.config(function($httpProvider) {
   $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
   $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
   $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
});
```

Comment: This code to work, we need to have csrf cookie set into the browser. My angular app is not served by django so how initially get this token from server ?

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem when i started to use Angular 1.x with Django and DRF, and then i found this code snippet in a book i think, and it works fine for me. Include this file in your `base.html` file or your main html file before any javascript import, and everything will work smoothly and you can start talking to your backend.

```js
// Place at /static/js/csrf.js
// CSRF helper functions taken directly from Django docs
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);

            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
// these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/ ˆ (GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE) $ /.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This code to work, we need to have csrf cookie set into the browser. My angular app is not served by django so how initially get this token from server ?